# Making an Array in chrome.storage and retrieving data

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-chrome-extension

So I'm in a bit of a dillema right now. I can't seem to be able to add an Array in chrome.storage and later retrieving it. Here's the code I have right now:

```
function() {
    chrome.storage.sync.get({ObjectName: []}, function (result) {
    var ObjectName = result.ObjectName;
    ObjectName.push({ArrayName: document.getElementById("field")});
    });
```

Now to retrieve it and display it:

```
chrome.storage.sync.get({ArrayName: function(value) {
            for(i=0; i<value.length; i++) { 
                document.write(value)
            };
```

The error I am getting, which might be as simple as a syntax issue, amounts to:

Error: Invocation of form get(object) doesn't match definition get(optional string or array or object keys, function callback)

Comment: store and load JSON in strings, you can't directly use objects

Comment: Actually, you can store object/arrays directly with the Storage API. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16605706/store-an-array-with-chrome-storage-local

Comment: I don't see any differences between the linked solution to mine yet I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: Your second get isn't correct syntax.  You have `get(object)` where `object` is `{ArrayName:function()}`.  You need `get(object,callback)`.

Answer (score 5):

You have to use set method to set values to chrome.storage

Here's an example of how to do it

To store an array to chrome storage using set

```
var testArray=["test", "teste", "testes"];

chrome.storage.sync.set({
    list:testArray
}, function() {
    console.log("added to list");
});
```

To get the arrayValue using get and modify if by calling updatemethod

```
chrome.storage.sync.get({
    list:[]; //put defaultvalues if any
},
function(data) {
   console.log(data.list);
   update(data.list); //storing the storage value in a variable and passing to update function
}
);  

function update(array)
   {
    array.push("testAdd");
    //then call the set to update with modified value
    chrome.storage.sync.set({
        list:array
    }, function() {
        console.log("added to list with new values");
    });
    }
```

Comment: Could you also show me how to update said array?

Comment: @Hamza You `get` the array, modify it and `set` it back, all in one callback chain.

Comment: @HamzaIbad I've added the code for update as well check it

Comment: This is [not going to work](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23667086/934239), unless it's all in one callback chain.

Comment: @Xan Thanks for the info.Modified code accordingly

Comment: You've error in the code, remove the ';' from the end of  list:[]; //put defaultvalues if any