# How to check an uninitialised chrome storage?

Tags: google-chrome-storage

I'm trying to check if the storage is empty, but it gives an error saying data needs to be `set` before it can even `get` from the storage.

```
chrome.storage.sync.get('pos', function(r){
   if (typeof r.pos === undefined ){

      }
    })
```

edit: The error I get is: `Invocation of form get(string) doesn't match definition get(optional string or array or object keys, function callback)
    at normalizeArgumentsAndValidate (extensions::schemaUtils:112:11)
    at StorageArea.self.(anonymous function) [as get] (extensions::StorageArea:35:14)
    at chrome-extension://lqhqq.....`

here is a similar question: [Making an Array in chrome.storage and retrieving data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31122797/making-an-array-in-chrome-storage-and-retrieving-data)

Comment: What's the error message specifically?

Comment: @JoshLee Added an edit.