# Saving array to local storage

Tags: javascript, arrays, async-await, local-storage, firefox-addon-webextensions

I'm new to WebExtensions and JavaScript. I'm trying to write a little extension with a `pageAction` button that simply saves the current URL to local storage when clicked (i.e. some very simple 'favourite' function). I am, however, having trouble with using `chrome.storage.local.set()` and `.get()`. I've been looking at code in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13872542/chrome-storage-local-get-and-set) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16605706/store-an-array-with-chrome-storage-local) to try and reuse it for my purposes, but failed miserably. Here is what I have at the moment.

The `saveURL()` function is supposed to load the array in local storage, update it with a new URL, and save it back to local storage (for now, I just have a dud string that I'm trying to push to that array).

```js
async function saveURL() {
  console.log("Save URL called.");
  var urls = await loadURLs();
  console.log(urls);
  urls.push("a-new-url")
  console.log(urls);
  chrome.storage.local.set({'pearsurls': urls});
  urls = await loadURLs();
  console.log(urls);
  return true;
}
```

The `loadURLs()` function is supposed to retrieve stuff from local storage. I'm using a default in `storage.local.get()` to initialise the array the first time it is used.

```js
function loadURLs(){
  var pearsurls = []
  console.log("Loading all saved URLs");
  chrome.storage.local.get({pearsurls: []}, function (result) {
    pearsurls = result.pearsurls;
    console.log(pearsurls)
  });
  console.log(pearsurls)
  return pearsurls;
}
```

The output in the console gives me:

```
Save page  save.js:52:3
Save URL called.  save.js:5:3
Loading all saved URLs  save.js:38:3
Array [  ]  save.js:43:3
Array [  ]  save.js:7:3
Array [ "a-new-url" ]  save.js:9:3
Loading all saved URLs  save.js:38:3
Array [  ]  save.js:43:3
Array [  ]
```

I.e. my `loadURLs()` function doesn't seem to be doing anything... What am I doing wrong?

Comment: While [edit]s to the question to provide additional information are encouraged, edits which change the question sufficiently to invalidate an already posted answer are not permitted. The consensus is that any user with [edit privileges](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit) should revert such edits. I will do so shortly after posting this comment. Please note that this does not prevent you from completely changing a question prior to any answers being posted. You should post a [new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) on your new issue.

Comment: You can find the source for your most recent changes [here](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/1162736c-800a-4305-ab4f-85c38a07153d/view-source). I hope that it assists in posting a [new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) on your new issue. It can also be beneficial to link to this question to provide context for your new question, but the new question should also be self contained. Please understand that a single question is *not* intended as an interactive debugging session. If you have new issues after getting answers, you should post a new question.

Comment: Note also that there's nothing wrong with a question being closed as a duplicate. Duplicates serve as signposts allowing other people who are searching for answers to find the answers on the duplicate-target.

Comment: Next time, please include a *complete* [mcve] that duplicates the problem. For Chrome extensions or Firefox WebExtensions this almost always means including your *manifest.json* and some of the background, content, and/or popup scripts/HTML. Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working the way I want?") must include: (1) the desired behavior, (2) a specific problem or error and (3) the shortest code necessary to reproduce it *in the question itself*. Please also see: [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and [ask].

Comment: For Firefox WebExtensions it's helpful if you *don't* break functions into separate code blocks. Please have all the code that you are showing which is contained in a single file in a single code block which explicitly specifies the file (e.g. normal text saying my *background.js*: [then a code block]. Problems/issues can significantly depend on exactly which file what code is in. Having code in a single code block *per file* makes it much easier to determine what's going on.

Comment: Ok! Apologies! I'll post to a new question.

Comment: No problem. You clearly didn't know. Unfortunately, there are things about Stack Overflow that are not clearly stated in most of the docs I've read from the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help). I was not intending to chastise. I was only intending to inform and facilitate you having the information (both policy and what you had written) for your next question. I look forward to seeing it.

Comment: Many thanks for all the advice! It will definitely help for the next question!

Answer (score 2):

You function `loadURLs` is not either `async` or returns a `Promise`, so it ends immediately with an empty array.

Try this instead:

```
function loadURLs(){
  console.log("Loading all saved URLs");
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    console.log("Promise");
    chrome.storage.local.get({pearsurls: []}, function (result) {
      console.log(result.pearsurls);
      resolve(result.pearsurls);
    });
  });
}
```

Note: your original function ends before `chrome.storage.local.get` is finished doing its job. The array `pearsurls` is first returned empty, and it gets populated anytime after the execution of the code, using the callback `function (result) ...`.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, but no, it doesn't seem to solve the problem. Now my saveURL() function doesn't print anything anymore to the console.

Comment: Does it freeze in the first or the second call to loadURLs?

Comment: Already the first time. Now my only output to the console are the 'Save URL...' and "Loading saved URLs" comments.

Comment: Did `console.log(result.pearsurls);` got called anytime?

Comment: Actually, no. Nothing.

Comment: Well, that's quite weird. I've added a `console.log`, can you debug if the promise is being executed?

Comment: Sorry for delayed answer. Yes, the promise is executed... Is there anything I should check outside of this call, which could be messing things up? I guess I could have made a mistake somewhere else...

Comment: All I see is that this snippet now with Promises should work according to chrome documentation. You could check if lastError is changed. https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime#property-lastError